# Is there any way to obtain the typename of a template type in a compiler warning message?

Tags: templates, c++17, compiler-warnings, preprocessor, static-assert

I would love to warn myself  or others when they use a T,U type template that auto converts silently but might be a questionable use case so that the programmer can verify if that template is appropriate (or if they made a mistake somewhere in their meta-logic).

But I'm failing to discern how one would generate such a compile time warning that named the types or referred to the caller's code in any way?

If it is a failure case - then I can issue a static_assert or similar to force the compiler to fail and then the user will see in the output diagnostics what originally triggered the failure case.

But what about a questionable use case?  Not necessarily an error... just a warning?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool within(T value, U minimum, U maximum)
{
    // WARNING: we force U to be a T silently
//#pragma message("Forcing " typeid(U).name() " to a " typeid(T).name())
#pragma message("Possible casting danger is happening in this template - check your types!")
    return static_cast<T>(minimum) <= value && value <= static_cast<T>(maximum);
}
```

Here I can't figure out how to name the T and U, nor how to get back to the caller's code...

I think I want a

```
static_warning(condition, "optional text which somehow also produces the actual typename of T and U");
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so I'd love to hear from the community about ways to generate compile time type-dependent warning messages...

but in the meantime, I realized that C++17 actually has the solution I need for this case and ones of a similar (T,U) vein:

```
// this will only compile if there is a common type for T and U! Neat! :D
template <typename T, typename U, typename Z = std::common_type_t<T,U>>
bool within(T value, U minimum, U maximum)
{
    return static_cast<Z>(minimum) <= value && value <= static_cast<Z>(maximum);
}
```